# python wand: creating text dropshadow

Tags: python, imagemagick, dropshadow, wand

Have anyone tried creating dropshadow with python wand? I went through this doc and couldn't find dropshadow attribute.

http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/drawing.html

---

According to imagemagick it is possible by doing below:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/

```
   convert -size 320x100 xc:lightblue -font Candice -pointsize 72 \
           -fill black -draw "text 28,68 'Anthony'" \
           -fill white -draw "text 25,65 'Anthony'" \
           font_shadow.jpg
```

How can I adapt this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Have anyone tried creating dropshadow with python wand?

There's a few techniques, and examples if you search the [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) tag.

> I went through this doc and couldn't find dropshadow attribute.

You would *not* see an attribute, as the dropshadow is nonsensical in vector drawing context. (at least I think)

Here's one approach / method for creating text dropshadows.

1. Draw shadow
2. Apply filter (optional)
3. Draw text

```py
from wand.color import Color
from wand.compat import nested
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.image import Image

dimensions = {'width': 450,
              'height': 100}

with nested(Image(background=Color('skyblue'), **dimensions),
            Image(background=Color('transparent'), **dimensions)) as (bg, shadow):
    # Draw the drop shadow
    with Drawing() as ctx:
        ctx.fill_color = Color('rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.6)')
        ctx.font_size = 64
        ctx.text(50, 75, 'Hello Wand!')
        ctx(shadow)
    # Apply filter
    shadow.gaussian_blur(4, 2)
    # Draw text
    with Drawing() as ctx:
        ctx.fill_color = Color('firebrick')
        ctx.font_size = 64
        ctx.text(48, 73, 'Hello Wand!')
        ctx(shadow)
    bg.composite(shadow, 0, 0)
    bg.save(filename='/tmp/out.png')
```

[image: Creating Text dropshadow]

**Edit** Here's another example that matches the Usage example.

```py
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.image import Image

# -size 320x100 xc:lightblue
with Image(width=320, height=100, background=Color('lightblue')) as image:
    with Drawing() as draw:
        # -font Candice
        draw.font = 'Candice'
        # -pointsize 72
        draw.font_size = 72.0
        draw.push()
        # -fill black
        draw.fill_color = Color('black')
        # -draw "text 28,68 'Anthony'"
        draw.text(28, 68, 'Anthony')
        draw.pop()
        draw.push()
        # -fill white
        draw.fill_color = Color('white')
        # -draw "text 25,65 'Anthony'"
        draw.text(25, 65, 'Anthony')
        draw.pop()
        draw(image)
    # font_shadow.jpg
    image.save(filename='font_shadow.jpg')
```

[image: font_shadow.jpg]

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful and I've accepted this as solution.

Comment: with the second example, if I want to add a opacity to dropshadow to make more subtle how would I approach it?

Comment: Try adjusting alpha channel on the shadows color. `Color('rgba(0,0,0,0.33)'` for example, or explore [HSL color theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) for subtle changes

Comment: Thanks @emcconville I am trying to find out how I can blur/spread the dropshadow, I can't seem to be able to find it. I think I am using photoshop terminology and it's not helping much with my search! Would you be able to assist please?

Comment: From your first example I can see that I need to use gaussian_blur(4, 2) but how do I apply it to your second example?
I get this error:
'Drawing' object has no attribute 'gaussian_blur'

Comment: You would apply the drawing context to an intermediate image instance, then invoke filters/enhancements on the image. Only after all the shadow has fx would you composite it to the source image, and redraw the top-layer text.